# Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) not working on unity android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hy, as the title says it doesn't work on android build (on windows dev works fine), this is the code:

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            if (bc == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition)) dragging = true;

        //make something

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            //make something
        }
    }
```

It only works GetMouseButtonDown(), GetMouseButtonUp() does not fired.
Also try using touch functions in the following way

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            if (bc == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition)) dragging = true;

        //make something

        if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            //make something
        }
    }
```

but without success

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
Because you are trying to get [mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) before even checking whether mouse is down or not.
also don't use [mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) on [GetMouseButtonUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html)

**Solution:**

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //Do Something On Touch End
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //Do Something On Touch Start
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Something during Touch
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
Check for [GetMouseButtonUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) before getting [mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) and use [mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) only on [GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) and on [GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html).

Comment: I will try, but my code on development windows works

Comment: yeah it will work on windows as even if you do not hold down mouse your mouse is still in the game but in case of android it is not. if you don't hold down touch then unity do not know where the pointer is.